# How to get client-side email forward rules by the office-js SDK?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I know how to get the server-side email forward rules by the GraphAPI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messagerules?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

It is possible to get the same local rules by the office-js SDK, for example?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by local rules as rules are for an account and are not client specific?

Comment: There a email forward rules that run on a server side and can be received by MSGraphAPI and there are the rules the exist locally in Outlook client. They run only when Outlook client is running and after the email is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature: client-side email forward rules, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Hi there. It's good that you're letting people know you are representing a brand, but your usercard does that just fine. There's no need to replicate that information in the post by way of a signature.